# approximation of the difference of a function using taylor series

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, taylor-expansion

How can I derive the below form for a function of two variables. The function is twice differentiable.

$f(y,x_1)$ and $f(y,x_2)$, then $\forall x_1,x_2$ $\exists c$ such that $x_1 < c <x_2$

$f(y,x_1) - f(y,x_2) = (x_1 - x_2)f'(y,x_1) - \frac{f''(y,c)}{2} (x_2 - x_1)^2$

The paper says, it is based on Taylor expansion. But using Taylor series, I am not able to get rid of the c coefficient of f'.

Comment: There were some small errors.

Comment: a) Youf problem is not for a function of two variables, since as you posed it, $y$ never changes.  b) Are you sure this was supposed to be for all $c$? I believe the correct statement is that if $x_1 << x_2$ then $\exists c: x_1 \leq c \leq x_2$ such that your next line holds for that value of $c$. c) Are you sure of the minus sign in front of the second derivative term?

Comment: @MarkFischler, it is for a fixed value of $y$. In fact the function is of two variables.  But for a fixed value of y, this holds.  Yes, this holds only for some value of c, not for all c.  Yes, the minus sign is there before the second derivative.  This equation is from the paper "Analysis of Two Gradient Based Algorithms for On-Line regression"  page 5, equation number 4.